# Complexity of two Methods

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

If I have a method that insert an element to an heap with the following code:

(1) If an array is full - create a new array and resize  by its `original.length * 2` , and then copy each elements from the original array to the new one.

(2). In order to fulfill an Heap just percup/perdown each element to its suit position.

So the worst case complexities are  - (1) is `O(n)` and for (2) its `O(logn)`

my question is what is the sum of the two complexities?  How to calculate the worst case complexity of this algorithm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For situations like this, if you follow the text book approach the worst case complexity of the algorithm would be

```
= O(n) + O(logn)
= O(n)
```

So, the complexity would be `O(n)`

---

Actually the name **worst case complexity** gives you the answer. You should ask yourself the question,

*Is there any case where the complexity is `O(n)`*.

If yes, then thats the **worst case complexity**

Comment: @BarakMi, Raed about time complexities from any algorithm book, you would find this concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting N elements one by one, then `siftUp/siftDown` process executes every time, and time dedicated to these procedures is O(NlogN) (as sum of `log1+log2+...log(N-1)+log(N)`)

But array expanding happens seldom. The last expanding takes N steps, previous N/2 steps and so on. Time dedicated to these procedures is

```
N + N/2 + N/4 + ...+1 = N*(1 + 1/2 +1/4+...) = N*2 = O(N)
```

So **amortized** time for expanding part is **O(1)**, and amortized time for inserting part is **O(logN)**

Overall complexity for N elements is
O(N) + O(NlogN) = **O(NlogN)**
or
O(logN) per element